# Why isn't spring using my constructor to init this bean (Map parameter)

Tags: java, spring, jackson

I have a spring beans configuration file where I define the following jackson classes as spring beans.
For some reason on run-time the `filterProvider` bean is instantiated without the map argument.
You can see from the [docs](http://jackson.codehaus.org/1.9.4/javadoc/org/codehaus/jackson/map/ser/impl/SimpleFilterProvider.html) that the `SimpleFilterProvider` does have such a constructor and that `SimpleBeanPropertyFilter` implements `BeanPropertyFilter`.

```
<bean id="productAttributesAndAdvertiserNameFilter" class="org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.impl.SimpleBeanPropertyFilter" factory-method="filterOutAllExcept">
        <constructor-arg value="name"/>
    </bean>
    <bean id="offerIdFilter" class="org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.impl.SimpleBeanPropertyFilter" factory-method="filterOutAllExcept">
        <constructor-arg value="id"/>
    </bean>
    <bean id="filterProvider" class="org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.impl.SimpleFilterProvider">
        <constructor-arg>
            <util:map value-type="org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.BeanPropertyFilter">
                <entry key="onlyNameFilter" value-ref="productAttributesAndAdvertiserNameFilter" />
                <entry key="onlyIdFilter" value-ref="offerIdFilter" />
            </util:map>
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>
```

**Update:**
As of Jackson 1.9.5 this issue is fixed (thanks Tatu)

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps you're using a different version of the method than the docs you're reading. Though I feel Spring would complain about a parameter mismatch. Do you have any stack trace?

Comment: @AHungerArtist The docs are for 1.9.4 and I'm using 1.9.2, I checked the docs for 1.9.2 and they're the same. Unfortunately I don't have any stack traces as Spring does not throw any errors. It just instantiates the bean with it's no arg constructor.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looks like you've found a bug in `SimpleFilterProvider`.

I just downloaded the latest sources (1.9.4) and the constructors are defined as such:

```
public SimpleFilterProvider() {
    _filtersById = new HashMap<String,BeanPropertyFilter>();
}

/**
 * @param mapping Mapping from id to filter; used as is, no copy is made.
 */
public SimpleFilterProvider(Map<String,BeanPropertyFilter> mapping) {
    _filtersById = new HashMap<String,BeanPropertyFilter>();
}
```

The constructor which takes the `mapping` ignores it... (i.e. javadoc is incorrect)

Comment: Ooh, nasty.  JIRA filed, Tatu's usually good at fixing these things quickly. http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/JACKSON-773

Answer (score 0):

I think `<util:map>` is misplaced here.  I'd make it a separate bean, outside of the filter provider declaration, and refer to it.  OR I'd change that to a `<map>` without the `util` namespace.

Comment: I'm not sure how that addresses the problem, though. Questions of style aside, it should still work.

Comment: @duffymo I tried extracting it to a separate bean before and it didn't work. I also tried changing to a `<map>` as per your suggest but it did not work...

Comment: @skaffman I agree. I can also say that when I took the map "outside" and autowired it somewhere just to see what's inside I saw the map is populated. The problem is with spring not using the argument when creating the bean.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why it is not working.

At worst, you can create your own class by extending the `SimpleFilterProvider` and declare this bean in your Spring context...